# How to make cursor show as vertical line in insert mode and as block in normal mode, in vim on iterm2

Tags: macos, vim, zsh, iterm2

How to change vim cursor to vertical line in insert mode, and block in normal mode, iterm2. mac osx

I have tried some other configs, i found online which said it would fix it but none of them worked. I have tried this, from [Vertical vim cursor in command mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904949/vertical-vim-cursor-in-command-mode):

```
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7"
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7"
```

I have also tried this one from this site https://hamberg.no/erlend/posts/2014-03-09-change-vim-cursor-in-iterm.html

```
if $TERM_PROGRAM =~ "iTerm"
    let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7" 
    let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7" 
endif
```

Nothing seems to be working, and the cursor still remains a block in both insert mode and normal mode. Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 4):

There is all you need to know in [this guide](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes).

```
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7"
let &t_SR = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=2\x7"
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7"
```

If you use `tmux`:

```
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7\<Esc>\\"
let &t_SR = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=2\x7\<Esc>\\"
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7\<Esc>\\"
```

Comment: I should point out that this works, but then you are left with a block cursor when you exit. See https://pastebin.com/iTje9b58 - The last line returns the cursor back to a line on `:q`.